# Using ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC applications within the same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, integration, asp.net-4.0

I have an ASP.NET **Web Forms** application in one project. Under the same solution I have two different projects: one **Repository** layer and one **Service** layer.

Eventually I will **rewrite** my ASP.NET Web Forms application in **MVC**, therefore I want to implement all the new functionality by using MVC.

I have to create a **registration form** for customers and at one point if a condition verifies, I have to bring the customer to another form and then back to the registration form.

Will it work if I create an MVC application project within the **same solution**? The application will also use the Service and Repository layers. What about the **Session object**?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the MVC controllers/views to your Web Forms application.  They can run side-by-side just fine.  This will allow you to upgrade parts of the site to MVC while keeping your existing Web Forms pages running.

The web layer (which has both MVC and Web Forms) can still access all of your application framework logic (repository, service, session, etc...)

Scott Hanselman created a Nuget Package for easily upgrading your web forms app to Mvc 3:
http://nuget.org/packages/AddMvc3ToWebForms